# Compute $\int_0^1 \left( \Gamma(x+1) - x^x\right) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Compute

$$\int_0^1 \left( \Gamma(x+1) - x^x\right) dx$$

... Where do I start. I can get the second term in series.  $\Gamma(x+1)$ is the "continuous" factorial.

Comment: This integral does not have antiderivative which could be expressed in terms of "elementary" functions. Do you need just the numerical value?

Comment: $\int_0^1 \left(\Gamma (x+1)-x^x\right) \, dx\approx 0.139315439968496198084616095818780107998919807664$

Answer (score 1):

Both $\Gamma(x+1)$ and $x^x$ are log-convex on $(0,1)$, hence almost any numerical method is able to produce accurate approximations of such integral.  A tailor-made approach comes from noticing that $\Gamma(x+1)-x^x$ approximately behaves like $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}(1-x)$ on $(0,1)$, hence very accurate approximations are expected from enforcing the substitution $x=u^2$, then applying Newton-Cotes formulas of moderately high order, like [Boole's rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoolesRule.html).

A closed form is hopeless, if not in terms of a fast-convergent series.